# The 'WHERE CONTAINS' statement issue after creating index for catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table (`Person_`) like this:

```
ID_   EN-EN_                           FR-FR_
1     English text description         French text description
2     Another english text             Parlez-vous francais ?
3     System embedded description      Il est un garcon
```

I created a catalog for this

```
create fulltext catalog [Person_Catalog] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
```

And an index

```
create fulltext index on Person_ ([EN-EN_],[FR-FR_])
    KEY INDEX PK_SOMEINDEX_
    ON Person_Catalog WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

`PK_SOMEINDEX_` already exists as a primary key constraint when I created `Person_` table

The problem is the following syntax:

```
select * from Person_ WHERE CONTAINS([EN-EN_],'english')
```

It returns 0 rows. (instead of 2 rows)

Why ?

Comment: What is your table definition?

Comment: ID is `INT NOT NULL IDENTITY`, `EN-EN_` and `FR-FR_` is varchar.

Comment: If `[EN-EN_]` and `[FR-FR_]` ar `VARCHAR`, why are you putting an `N` before english?. What happens if you do `WHERE CONTAINS([EN-EN_],'english')`?

Comment: I've edited by removing that `N`...Same result: 0 rows.

Comment: When I created that index, the values are not added into catalog automatically or I have to do manually ?

Comment: Does it work with other words? (Ie. 'embedded'). If so, have you checked that 'english' has not - accidentally - landed in the stop word list?

Comment: I don't created STOP List...Have I to create this?

Comment: Waiting a couple of minutes after creating the index and before querying it, it worked fine for me. (Incidentally, you ought to specify the `language` in your `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX` statement, so that the `FR-FR_` column is correctly indexed)

Comment: When I want to populate, the warning appears: `table or indexed view  is ignored because a population is currently active for this table or indexed view.` What is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how long did you wait to run your test. See the last line from this paragraph:

By default, or if you specify CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO, the Full-Text Engine uses automatic population on the full-text index. After the initial full population completes, changes are tracked as data is modified in the base table, and the tracked changes are propagated automatically. The full-text index is updated in the background, however, so propagated changes might not be reflected immediately in the index.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx

Comment: for three records, maybe I have to wait one year ?

Comment: try to run it manually:
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON Person_Catalog START UPDATE POPULATION;

Comment: @MichaelSwan - If you execute `select * from sys.fulltext_indexes` immediately after executing the `create fulltext index` statement, you'll find that `has_crawl_completed` is false. If you wait a minute and run it again, it will be true (based on your sample data)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: `has_crawl_completed` is true.  @Diego: I run it but same issue

Comment: @MichaelSwan - then there's something different in your setup compared to your example above - in the example setup, once `has_crawl_completed` is true, 2 rows are returned.

Comment: can you post the exact structure of your table?

Comment: I've already answered to this question. Is same, nothing modified. same structure.